# I have Issue with parent component method hit in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have 3 levels of components.
first component is a MAIN component second is SIDEBAR component third component is location.

[image]

I have button in location component. when i click on it i want to hit main component function. how i can achieve this without use two times @output?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `SharedService`. Inject this `SharedService` in all the components where you want to share the data.

Something like this:

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  private sharedData: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  public sharedData$: Observable<any> = this.sharedData.asObservable();

  setSharedData(sharedData) {
    this.sharedData.next(sharedData);
  }
}
```

Now just inject the `SharedService` as a Dependency in your `LocationComponent` and your `MainComponent`

From `LocationComponent` call the `setSharedData` method on the `SharedService` instance.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-location',
  templateUrl: './location.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./location.component.css']
})
export class LocationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.setSharedData({ foo: 'bar' });
  }

}
```

And then also `subscribe` to the `sharedData$` in the `ngOnInit` of the MainComponent.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sharedService.sharedData$
      .subscribe(sharedData => console.log('Got the shared data in the main component as: ', sharedData));
  }

}
```

---

Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-shared-service-eg?file=src/app/main/main.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: thanks for your response... I love the way of your explanation.. actually i have issue with hit parrent method from location component.. pls check again stackblitz i added there button in location.html file and create method in main.ts file

Comment: @AnilRayat, you'll have to fork my StackBlitz to create yours. Once you do that, you can make changes to it and share it across here so that I can have a look into it.

Comment: Yes i did please check....
for reference you can see this site.. https://mapkit.io/editor
in this site have location tab click then add location there.. after that every location have drop-down you can select from there "pan to" almost same my functionality... but my all maps functions are declare in main component.. but buttons is in location tab.. so i dont understand how i can hit parrent method with some paramenters

Answer (score 0):

To make this simple, You can create a AppNotificationService which has the EventEmmiter as below. And then use this service in both component.

```
export class AppNotificationService {
    buttonClicked: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
    emitbuttonClickedEvent(id) {
        this.buttonClicked.emit(id);
    }

    getbuttonClickedEvent() {
    return this.buttonClicked;
    }
}

class LocationComponent{
    onClick(){
        this.appNotificationService.emitbuttonClickedEvent("id");
    }
}

class MainComponent{

    ngOnInit(){
        this.appNotificationService.getbuttonClickedEvent().subscribe((item)=>{
            this.callThisOnButtonClick();
        });
    }

    callThisOnButtonClick(){
          Console.log("Message from Main Component when button clicked in Location Service")
    }

}
```

Also you can create multiple EventEmitter in AppNotificationService.

Comment: thanks its working... how can i send parameters with.. ? I want to pass id from ngfor.. but how i got that in callThisOnButtonClick function